# Yii2 Call to undefined method setuser

Tags: yii2, registration, undefined-function

I'm using Yii2 module dektrium/yii2-user for user sign-up/sign-in and get the aforementioned error while trying to register.

```
PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException.
in C:\xampp\htdocs\hello\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php
```

How do I find out the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be very careful when configuring mailer component of your app. The problem was a typo:

```
'viewpath' => '@app/mailer',
```

instead of

```
'viewPath' => '@app/mailer',
```

in /appName/config/web.php